# Robustness check in Structural Equation Modelling (SEM) in R

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, robust

I have conducted SEM analysis in R and used Maximum Likelihood Robust estimator as my data are categorical and deviate from multivariate normality. when I submitted my manuscript, one reviewer asked for robustness analysis.

I have been searching for such analyses in R but I cannot find anything. I only see resources about robustness check for example for endogeneity, unobserved heterogeneity, and non-linear effects in PLS-SEM mostly in SmartPLS software. I'm confused whether I need to do robustness analysis and if yes, how it can be done in R. I appreciate any input in this regard.

Comment: I've never heard of this. I'd request more information from the reviewer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the reviewer would like to see an analysis of your model with alternative estimation methods for categorical (I assume you mean ordinal = ordered categorical) indicator variables such as, for example, WLSMV/DWLS to see if such alternative methods would result in similar findings as your robust ML approach.